# fatal error: 'libpq++' file not found

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I would love to use libpq++ library in my C++ project but I am unable to get it working.

So far, I have installed `libpqxx-dev libpqxx-4.0` packages on my Ubuntu 14.04 and provided -llibpq++ to clang++.

However, no matter what I do, I still get following error:

```
src/serverdata.h:4:10: fatal error: 'libpq++' file not found
```

It seems that I didn't install libpq++ properly but I don't really see any problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, your `src/serverdata.h` has 4th line like:

```
#include "libpq++"
```

If so, change it to something like:

```
#include <pqxx/basic_connection.hxx>
```

PS. Files in dev packet are listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/lucid/amd64/libpqxx-dev/filelist)